# Find percentage of color with respect to another color in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, stylesheet

I need to change the color of a div element based on the color of another div element.

Ex.

```
 <div style="background-color:{{color_primary}};">
```

In another DIV, the color should be 70% (light shade) of the color_primary

```
<div style="background-color:{{this color is 70% of color_primary}};">
```

How can I achieve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are your colours in? Hex/RGB/RGBa/Named? With some types this could be pretty simple maths, with others it may be significantly more complex.

Comment: color comes in like Hex or named like #FFFFFF or white

Comment: With the hex values, you should be able to divide it into its components (`#A1B2C3` R = `A1`, G = `B2`, B = `C3`), convert each of those to decimal `parseInt(R, 16);` then do the maths (number * 0.7) and do the process in reverse to put the colour back together. With your named colours I'm afraid I don't know how you could work it out.

Comment: I've tried the above method for HEX, but it's not giving the right value

Comment: This code works for me - > https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by applying this percentage to every RGB component, similar to how SASS and LESS helpers do. So then, you can use it to modify a color property inside your angularjs application.

The following example demonstrate the usage of a simple API that I've created for this issue that is exposed as a service in the colorized module.

> Disclaimer, it's just a simple module to demonstrate how it can be done, it means I'm not catching all errors and exceptions that could be thrown. Regardless, it's a beautiful module and I'm very proud of it :{D

Usage

```
angular.module('myApp', ['colorized'])    
    .controller('myController', function ($colors) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.myLightenColor = $colors.lighten('#000000', 50); // 50% gray        
    });
```

The `colorized` module plus a simple example:

```js
// The module
(function() {
  angular.module('colorized', [])
    .service('$colors', function() {

      this.lighten = function(src, percent) {

        var src = normalizeColor(src);

        if (!percent) return src;

        var srcRGB = colorAsArray(src),
          // you may want to change it to keep a different
          // range, for example, the range between the actual
          // collor and the full white collor, it's up to you
          lightFactor = (255 * percent) / 100,
          newRGB = {
            r: limited(srcRGB.r + lightFactor, 255),
            g: limited(srcRGB.g + lightFactor, 255),
            b: limited(srcRGB.b + lightFactor, 255),
          };

        return [
          padRGBDigit(newRGB.r.toString(16)),
          padRGBDigit(newRGB.g.toString(16)),
          padRGBDigit(newRGB.b.toString(16))
        ].join('');
      }

      function normalizeColor(color) {
        if (color == undefined) color = '000000';
        if (color[0] == '#') color = color.substring(1);

        return color;
      }

      function colorAsArray(color) {
        return {
          r: parseInt(color.substring(0, 2), 16),
          g: parseInt(color.substring(2, 4), 16),
          b: parseInt(color.substring(4, 8), 16),
        };
      }

      function limited(value, limit) {
        return Math.ceil(value > limit ? limit : value);
      }

      function padRGBDigit(str) {
        return ('00' + str).slice(-2);
      }

    });
})();
// my app
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', ['colorized'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, $colors) {
      $scope.mySourceColor = '#000000';
      $scope.myPercentage = 50;
      $scope.myLightColor = function() {
        return '#' + $colors.lighten($scope.mySourceColor, $scope.myPercentage);
      };
    });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="color" ng-model="mySourceColor">
  <input ng-style="{'background-color': myLightColor()}" type="range" ng-model="myPercentage" min="0" max="100">
  <span>
  {{ myLightColor() }}
</span>
</div>
```